# My web page is saying that this page is accessing camera but I'm not able to see Webcam on my page

Tags: javascript, canvas

My web page is saying that this page is accessing the camera, but I'm not able to see the Webcam on my page.
Please let me know If I need to change any settings.
    //html code for video and canvas tag. Below is the code to display

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
```

javascript script.js

```
//To Access Camera
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">

        </div><br></br><br></br><br></br>
        <div class="login-box animated fadeInUp">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h2>Face Detect</h2>
            </div>
            <button type="submit"><a onclick="onStream()">Start</a></button>

            <br/>
        </div>
        <video id="video" width="10" height="10" autoplay></video>
            <canvas style="float:right" id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

and

```
var canvas, context, video, videoObj; 
function onStream() { 
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
  video = document.getElementById("video"); 
  var constraints = { 
    audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } 
  }; 
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) .then(function(mediaStream) { 
    var video = document.querySelector('video'); 
    video.srcObject = mediaStream; video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) { 
      video.play(); 
    }; 
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) (below the headline "Using the new API in older browsers")? You might have to use srcObject and onloadedmetadata.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it and i can't able to see my webcam but I heard huge noisy behind the screen. I think it might be microphone sound.

Comment: <body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="top">
   
  </div><br></br><br></br><br></br>
  <div class="login-box animated fadeInUp">
   <div class="box-header">
    <h2>Face Detect</h2>
   </div>
   <button type="submit"><a onclick="onStream()">Start</a></button>
   
   <br/>
  </div>
  <video id="video" width="10" height="10" autoplay></video>
   <canvas style="float:right" id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
 </div>
</body>

Comment: var canvas, context, video, videoObj;
function onStream() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            video = document.getElementById("video");

          var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
})
}

Comment: These two lines are my code snippet. Please let me know if i need to modify anything.

Comment: add a `catch` after your `getUserMedia` call to check what's going wrong. (your second version is better, (though the size constraints may be the problem with your hardware): don't use `URL.createObjectURL` with a MediaStream, it will block the hardware. `srcObject` is indeed the correct way.

Comment: Thanks Kalido. I have used  srcObject also but its still same problem. Is there any chrome settings need to be changed. The page is accessing my camera but I am not able to see camera on chrome browser.